# How to use job parameter or environment variable in Jenkins for archiving artifacts?

Tags: jenkins

I have got a little issue with archiving artifacts using Jenkins

I would like to use a 'job parameter' (or environment variable) to archive the artifacts

I tried the following options in 'Files to archive' but nothing worked

```
1)  **/${MODULE_NAME}/*.dll
2)  **/$MODULE_NAME/*.dll
3)  **/%MODULE_NAME%/*.dll
4)  **/$ENV:MODULE_NAME/*.dll
```

Kindly let me know whether there's any way to use 'job parameter' or 'environment variable' in Jenkins

Answer (score 2):

I checked and you're doing that correctly (I tried to use `**/${MODULE_NAME}/*.txt` in `Files to archive` section). Here is my test configuration:
[image]
and
[image]

So, it's ok to have this error:

`‘**/${MODULE_NAME}/*.txt’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’ exists but not ‘**/${MODULE_NAME}/*.txt’`

When I run the job everything is fine. In my case, console output is:

```
Started by user admin
Building on master in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/freestyle
[freestyle] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins6987280264619488185.sh
+ cd directory1/directory2/directory3
+ touch test.txt
+ echo 24
+ ls
test.txt
Archiving artifacts
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I recommend you to check other part of configuration and also check if your file is created in the right path.

Comment: Yes I have tried it this solution is working, simply using pattern like so: Installer/*_${VERSION}.exe

Answer (score 1):

If you enclose the artifacts: parameter containing the variable in double quotes, instead of single quotes, it will parse the contained variable(s)

Answer (score 0):

I guess is not possible yet to expand variables, you must pre-parse the files before archiving.

[JENKINS-5758](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-5758)